# Sort one dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, sorting

Lets say I have two dataframes abc and xyz:

```
 abc
 batch_id    file_number  
 1            23.OH3
 1            28.OG2
 2            28.OI1
 2            40.OE1

 xyz
 file_number
 28.OI1
 23.OH3
 40.OE1
 28.OG2
```

How can I sort `xyz$file_number` based on `abc$file_number`

Comment: Not clear what the expected output is. Perhaps `xyz[match(abc$file_number, xyz$file_number),, drop=FALSE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that tables has same number of rows...

```
order_vec <- order(xyz$filenumber)
abc[order_vec,]
```

Comment: did you mean to use `order_vec` on the second code line?  Also, even with that not sure that's actually what OP is asking for (see @akrun's comment)

Comment: You re totally right... Corrected. I was not sure either, but I guessed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
order.index <- sapply(xyz$filenumber, function(x) which(abc$file_number==x))
xyz$file_number[order.index]
```