# How can I sort a dataframe based on other dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708144/sort-one-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe) but in Python. Furthermore, I would also like to have the option to keep the indexes or not and also drop any rows that their entries do not appear to the reference dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the column you want to order your other `DataFrame` on as an index:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = ['23.OH3', '28.OG2', '28.OI1', '40.OE1', '50.OF1']
d2 = ['28.OI1', '23.OH3', '40.OE1', '28.OG2']

abc_d = {'batch_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'file_number': d1}
xyz_d = {'file_name': d2}

abc = pd.DataFrame(data = abc_d)
xyz = pd.DataFrame(data = xyz_d)

idx = pd.Index(xyz.file_name)
abc.set_index('file_number').loc[idx].reset_index()
```

It should work as long as `len(abc) >= len(xyz)`, rows that are missing in `xyz` will be dropped.

**Edit:** You can drop missing rows, regardless of `len(abc)` and `len(xyz)` this way:

```
d1 = ['23.OH3', '28.OG2', '28.OI1', '40.OE1']
d2 = ['28.OI1', '23.OH3', '40.OE1', '28.OG2', '50.OF1']

abc_d = {'batch_id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'file_number': d1}
xyz_d = {'file_number': d2}

abc = pd.DataFrame(data = abc_d)
xyz = pd.DataFrame(data = xyz_d)

idx = pd.Index(xyz.file_number)
not_missing = xyz.file_number.isin(abc.file_number)
idx = idx[not_missing]
abc.set_index('file_number').loc[idx].reset_index()
```

Comment: The code does not drop the rows that are missing. It creates them assigning NaN. In my case xyz  > abc

Comment: You can use `.isin()` on `file_number` column to fix this (see edit), or you could use `.dropna()`.